# Tensorboard graph visualization, no graph was generated

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

[image]I am following 
https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/5%20-%20User%20Interface/loss_visualization.py
to visualize tensorflow.

What I did (on Pycharm) :

- Step 1, run the .py code.
- Step 2, View - Tool windows - Terminal, and type in "tensorboard --logdir=/tmp/tensorflow_logs"
- Then I was expecting to see some graph like https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/how_tos/graph_viz/index.html

However, on my browser http://localhost:6006/ , there is no graph generated, though it seems that tensorboard was launched. Please refer to the attached screenshots.

What I missed ? Thanks a lot.

(Beginner question.... Thanks for understanding)

[image]

Comment: Did you see some files /tmp/tensorflow_logs? "I am following" are you running the same code or modified?

Comment: Thanks Sung for response. Yes I saw files in the folder of  /tmp/tensorflow_logs, like "events.out.tfevents.1462675962.Mycomputer-iMac.local" . I ran the same file, did not modify anything. Could you shed a light ? Thank you

Comment: Did you change anything in the code? Or just running the example?

Comment: I did not change anything in the code -- simply copy and paste, and the ran it.  / I do have a graph of "Event -- loss", but what I am expecting is the tensor flow graph.

Comment: In that case, can you run this code? https://github.com/nlintz/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/9_tensorboard.py What tensorflow version are you using? Are you using the latest version? rc0.8 on Mac had a CSS issue.

Comment: I'm using tensorflow version 0.8.0 on Mac. What is rc0.8 , I mean, what rc stands for ? Thanks

Comment: release candidate. If you are using the latest version, it's OK. Anyway, it's weird. It should work. :-)

Comment: What browser are you using? Your TensorBoard doesn't look quite right. Also, can you see the graph here? https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/index.html#graphs